# Hadith about Dajjal One Eye Lord is not one Eyed?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Can you please explain this hadith from the classical muhadditheen scholars and sources. Why is Allah being compared to the Dajjal does this mean Allah will look like Esa?

Anas b. Malik reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said:
There is never a prophet who has not warned the Ummah of that one-eyed liar; behold he is one-eyed and your Lord is not one-eyed. On his forehead are the letters k f. r. (Kafir).

جَعْفَرٍ، حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ قَتَادَةَ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ أَنَسَ بْنَ مَالِكٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ مَا مِنْ نَبِيٍّ إِلاَّ وَقَدْ أَنْذَرَ أُمَّتَهُ الأَعْوَرَ الْكَذَّابَ أَلاَ إِنَّهُ أَعْوَرُ وَإِنَّ رَبَّكُمْ لَيْسَ بِأَعْوَرَ وَمَكْتُوبٌ بَيْنَ عَيْنَيْهِ ك ف ر ‏"

Reference    : Sahih Muslim 2933 a
In-book reference    : Book 54, Hadith 127
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Book 41, Hadith 7007
  (deprecated numbering scheme)

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? As for the question, I don't see how god is compared to the dajjal here; if I say "apples are round and functions are not round", am I comparing functions to apples, or implying anything about functions?

Comment: Can you please provide a reference or an Arabic original of the hadith?

Comment: Sure its there....

Comment: The hadith neither is about 'Isa nor does it compare Allah with 'Isa.

Answer (score 1):

The context here is that many people/nations/tribes in the time of Dajjal will believe that he is God (Allah).

The hadith follow has a guidance to the believers before they may think that "Dajjal is Allah". Saying "..your Lord is not one-eyed". Meaning that Dajjal cannot be God because being one-eyed indicates someone has limited faculty of sight. Allah (swt) is perfect and is not limited. He Allah (swt) is free from imperfection.

In that context it doesn't matter if you go for a literal or a philosophical interpretation. Most scholars who either adopt one or the other will always indicate to you that the Dajjal is not perfect, this is one of the main lesson to take from this hadith.

But in the time of Dajjal, people will see him performing miracles and to the people who follow him, they might see him as perfect.

So the hadith doesn't really compare Allah (swt) with the Dajjal, but simply expose one of the many imperfection of Dajjal. In the sense how can you compare the Dajjal with Allah, when the Dajjal has imperfection and Allah(swt) has no imperfection.

> The above contain opinion based explanation.

Also if you study the subject of Dajjal it also required of you that you also understand the principals of faith. One of them is that Allah(swt) has no human comparison and is not in need of one. He is above all that which we may think of in terms of appearance, power, majesty, etc...

> https://islamqa.info/en/992

There is also some explanation to certain hadith here.

> https://islamqa.info/en/8806

**May Allah(swt) guide us, preserve us and protect us from the Dajjal.**

Answer (score 0):

"One Eye" also implies that the Dajjal will mislead the people by attracting them to money, wealth, materilialism and luxurious. He will engage the people in these things that peolple will forget the other side of fact, which is Judgement day and Life after this world. Like we can see today people are focusing only on making money and having women. Materialism is ao much common that people have forgot the importance of relationships. People don't care about the source of money. People even kill other people for money. All this is one side and one eye.

Answer (score 0):

Why Rasulullah s.a.w had to mention the word 'eyes' when Allah's dzat is not the same as human being?

> Sura Al-Ikhlaas 112 : 4
>
> وَلَمْ يَكُنْ لَهُ كُفُوًا أَحَدٌ
>
> Nor is there to Him any equivalent.

For the same argument, why does Rasulullah had to compare Allah s.w.t with Dajjal?

The subject of comparison and the matter gives us a hint.

Now let's focus on the word 'eye' for a moment. الأَعْوَرَ
For obvious reason, the eye is related to **sight** or the **ability to see**.

What does the Qur'an explain about sight?

> Sura Al-Hajj 22 : 46
>
> أَفَلَمْ يَسِيرُوا فِي الْأَرْضِ فَتَكُونَ لَهُمْ قُلُوبٌ يَعْقِلُونَ
> بِهَا أَوْ آذَانٌ يَسْمَعُونَ بِهَا ۖ فَإِنَّهَا لَا تَعْمَى
> الْأَبْصَارُ وَلَٰكِنْ تَعْمَى الْقُلُوبُ الَّتِي فِي الصُّدُورِ
>
> So have they not travelled through the earth and have hearts by which
> to reason and ears by which to hear? For indeed, **it is not eyes that
> are blinded, but blinded are the hearts which are within the
> breasts.**

The establishment of *'internal sight'* by Allah showed that there is possibility that Dajjal is blind in the *'internal eye'*. Means, his understanding of the world is based on material-reality, scientific, and physically-driven. He's the one who wants to show everything with visuals so that people can believe in him without any doubt. Whereas, Allah is 'ghaib'(unseen) to the eyes.

So when Dajjal comes with miracles that can be seen with physical eyes, many would believe him when he proclaims he's god. When there is no God but Allah.

Sometimes the role of *faith* requires you to believe in the unseen and put your hope in Allah.

**But in akhirruzaman, this is not enough.**

Why?

Because Dajjal is blind in one eye, so there is a possibility that he's blind on the other side too.

> Sura Al-Baqara 2 : 7
>
> خَتَمَ اللَّهُ عَلَىٰ قُلُوبِهِمْ وَعَلَىٰ سَمْعِهِمْ ۖ وَعَلَىٰ
> أَبْصَارِهِمْ غِشَاوَةٌ ۖ وَلَهُمْ عَذَابٌ عَظِيمٌ
>
> Allah has set a seal upon their hearts and upon their hearing, and
> **over their vision is a veil**. And for them is a great punishment.

As the saying goes,

> "In the Country of the Blind, the One-Eyed Man is King"

So Allah, sees with more than one eye! If you care to understand the meaning of *'eye'* and *'sight'* based from the Qur'an and the hadith, then you'd see Dajjal now!

There are two Names of Allah that will serve to explain what Dajjal is missing :

1. AZ-DHAAHIR (The One That Manifest) - ٱلْظَّاهِرُ
2. AL-BAATIN (The One That is Hidden) - ٱلْبَاطِنُ

If you don't see both the Dhaahir and the Baatin, you won't be able to see through Dajjal's deceptions. Because he will be blind in either one.

When I say Dajjal, I don't just mean the Al-Masih Ad-Dajjal which is the main Dajjal that will impersonate the Messiah Isa a.s. I'm talking about the 30 Dajjals(liars) as well.

> اَ تَقُومُ السَّاعَةُ حَتَّى يَخْرُجَ ثَلاَثُونَ كَذَّابًا دَجَّالاً
> كُلُّهُمْ يَكْذِبُ عَلَى اللَّهِ وَعَلَى رَسُولِهِ
>
> Narrated Abu Hurayrah:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: The Last Hour will not come before there come
> forth **thirty liar Dajjals (fraudulents) lying on Allah and His
> Apostle.**
>
> Grade: Hasan in chain (Al-Albani)
> Reference : Sunan Abi Dawud 4334
> In-book reference : Book 39, Hadith 44
> English translation : Book 38, Hadith 4320

These liars will use Allah's and His messenger's name to spread lies. He will ask you to be **one-eyed Muslim**, to only focus on *ibadah*(ritual) and avoid questioning the *deeper meaning*(spiritual). So that people will focus on their dzikr but let his brothers and sisters in Islam die in hunger. So that the scholars will debate, debate, debate like there's no tomorrow but the ummah still doing zina and big sins. So that the fundamental issues will not be addressed because Islam to all of them, are merely ritual. Like collecting points for your membership card so that you can redeem later. He can also come as a spiritual teacher that makes you avoid worldly affairs and only focus on Allah. Only *Hablu Minallah*(relationship with Allah), without *Hablu Minannas*(relationship with mankind).

> Sura Aal-i-Imraan 3 : 112
>
> ضُرِبَتْ عَلَيْهِمُ الذِّلَّةُ أَيْنَ مَا ثُقِفُوا إِلَّا بِحَبْلٍ
> مِنَ اللَّهِ وَحَبْلٍ مِنَ النَّاسِ وَبَاءُوا بِغَضَبٍ مِنَ اللَّهِ
> وَضُرِبَتْ عَلَيْهِمُ الْمَسْكَنَةُ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ بِأَنَّهُمْ كَانُوا
> يَكْفُرُونَ بِآيَاتِ اللَّهِ وَيَقْتُلُونَ الْأَنْبِيَاءَ بِغَيْرِ
> حَقٍّ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ بِمَا عَصَوْا وَكَانُوا يَعْتَدُونَ
>
> They have been put under humiliation [by Allah] wherever they are
> overtaken, **except for a covenant from Allah and a rope from the
> Muslims**. And they have drawn upon themselves anger from Allah and
> have been put under destitution. That is because they disbelieved in
> the verses of Allah and killed the prophets without right. That is
> because they disobeyed and [habitually] transgressed.

On the other side, there will be liberal Dajjals whose focus is only on materialistic gains and physical world view. *Nothing is without science. Science explains everything. What title does he have? Doctor? PhD? Dato? How much money does he make monthly? What car does he drive*? You have to satisfy their *physical capacity* before they can even listen to you and they will drive you to their material world before you know it.

What Rasulullah wanted was for you to **open both *'eyes'*, and see from both angles**. Like understanding Covid-19 in scientific views, listen to scientists from all sides, before getting to the debate of Fiqh. Because if one does not do that, the debate will go round and round and round. And the next day, we will be back to square one. Because the fundamental issue has never been addressed in the first place! There can never be the right answer without first asking the right question.

Dajjal already came on both ends, corrupting political leaders as well as religious leaders through the systematic **education system**. So when the ummah is divided into two, it's not because one of them is correct. It's because both of them can be wrong as well!

> "...During it a man will be a believer in the morning and an infidel
> in the evening, so that the people will be in two camps: the camp of
> faith which will contain no hypocrisy, and the camp of hypocrisy which
> will contain no faith. When that happens, expect the Antichrist
> (Dajjal) that day or the next."
>
> Grade : Sahih (Al-Albani)
> Reference : Sunan Abi Dawud 4242
> In-book reference : Book 37, Hadith 3
> English translation : Book 36, Hadith 4230

You will never see Dajjal if you don't open two eyes. He can come as a faithful man and you'll be deceived.

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Let him who hears of the Dajjal (Antichrist) go
> far from him for I swear by Allah that **a man will come to him thinking
> he is a believer and follow him because of confused ideas roused in
> him by him**.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُوسَى بْنُ إِسْمَاعِيلَ، حَدَّثَنَا جَرِيرٌ، حَدَّثَنَا
> حُمَيْدُ بْنُ هِلاَلٍ، عَنْ أَبِي الدَّهْمَاءِ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ
> عِمْرَانَ بْنَ حُصَيْنٍ، يُحَدِّثُ قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى
> الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ مَنْ سَمِعَ بِالدَّجَّالِ فَلْيَنْأَ عَنْهُ
> فَوَاللَّهِ إِنَّ الرَّجُلَ لَيَأْتِيهِ وَهْوَ يَحْسِبُ أَنَّهُ
> مُؤْمِنٌ فَيَتَّبِعُهُ مِمَّا يُبْعَثُ بِهِ مِنَ الشُّبُهَاتِ أَوْ
> لِمَا يُبْعَثُ بِهِ مِنَ الشُّبُهَاتِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ هَكَذَا قَالَ ‏.‏
>
> Grade : Sahih (Al-Albani)
> Reference : Sunan Abi Dawud 4319
> In-book reference : Book 39, Hadith 29
> English translation : Book 38, Hadith 4305

There are a lot of hadith that showed even until the end, many people cannot see who's the real Dajjal. There will be one man who will come forth before Dajjal and say to his face that "You are Dajjal".

> One day Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) narrated to us a long narration about
> Ad-Dajjal and among the things he narrated to us, was:
>
> "Ad-Dajjal will come, and he will be forbidden to enter the mountain
> passes of Medina. He will encamp in one of the salt areas neighboring
> Medina and there will appear to him a man who will be the best or one
> of the best of the people.
>
> He will say,
>
> 'I testify that you are Ad-Dajjal whose story Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
> has told us.'
>
> Ad-Dajjal will say (to his audience),
>
> 'Look, if I kill this man and then give him life, will you have any
> doubt about my claim?'
>
> They will reply, 'No,'
>
> Then Ad- Dajjal will kill that man and then will make him alive.
>
> The man will say,
>
> 'By Allah, now I recognize you more than ever!'
>
> Ad-Dajjal will then try to kill him (again) but he will not be given
> the power to do so."
>
> Reference  : Sahih al-Bukhari 7132
> In-book reference : Book 92, Hadith 79

My conclusion. Many people will not know who is the real Al-Masih Ad-Dajjal because they haven't been able to discern and open *two eyes* wide enough. For many people from the camp of the hypocrites AND the camp of those who have faith will be deceived.

So, start sharpening both of your eyes now, or later, you will be following the One-Eyed King.

Assalamualaikum,
Azrin

Answer (score -2):

I will explain as much things as I know about Dajjal.

1. Dajjal is the False Messiah.
2. Dajjal is Fast like Sonic the Hedgehog.
3. Dajjal has Thick Hair that is so Thick u think it is a Snake.
4. Dajjal will pretend to be Allah.
5. Dajjal will help his Followers that believe in him.
6. Prophet Jesus PBUH will Kill Dajjal.
7. Dajjal has the word Infidel written in his head in Arabic.
8. Dajjal will be fooling people for EX. If I bring ur animal back to live if u accept me as ur Allah and Satan will transform to the Person’s Dead Animal.
9. Dajjal was believe in 2 ways he has 1 open eye and 1 closed eye or he is a cyclops.
10. Dajjal claims that he is a Prophet.
    BONUS. If u know the 10 Versus in the Quran or Hadith u will be protected from Dajjal.

Comment: Would you mind sharing evidences supporting your claims?